# Why did Mewtwo need Tim?

Tags: pokemon, pokemon-detective-pikachu

At the end of *Pokémon: Detective Pikachu* it is revealed that:

> Harry was inside of Pikachu all along, placed there by Mewtwo because Harry was dying. Mewtwo told Pikachu to find the boy so that Mewtwo could restore Harry.

Why was the boy (Tim) needed?

Answer (score 8):

If memory serves, the dialogue doesn't state more than "with the return of the son, I can fix the body" (or something similar).

Upon watching the movie, I assumed that Mewtwo, despite all its power, was unable to fully generate a new body (organs and the like, which probably suffered a lot of damage in the car crash).

Thus, it would need Tim to provide body material (stem cells? DNA?); as Tim is Harry's son, maybe Mewtwo could produce/fix the new body with "healthy" bits of Tim. Kind of like in real life, some cells donations work better if they come from a family member.

Note that it also ties in nicely with the movie's overall "father and son finding each other again" theme.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable explanation, but we never hear/see anything suggesting that Mewtwo can create new bodies so it seems more like speculation.